# How to use ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock with Inline code?

Tags: asp.net

I have aspx page where there is no code behind. Server side Code written inside  tag with runat server attribute.

If i use

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Email", "GetEmail();");
```

in `page_load()` event, it just print `GetEmail();` when page load

My code looks like

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function GetEmail()
            {
                alert('hi');
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
           Some control here
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Email", "GetEmail();");
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `true` as the last argument to [RegisterClientScriptBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) in order for your client-side code to be wrapped in a `<script>` element:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Email",
        "GetEmail();", true);
}
```