# try to download file from asp.net server and using UpdatePanel, ProgressTemplate.. But not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Want to make some actions in my program.
While these actions run I want to tell the client that these actions are on process.
and after this process end, I want to send to the client this file for example Excel file.
I minimize my project to show exactly where the problem is

Now, this is my problem: 
Button1 does not work, And Button2 works fine why? and how to fix that?
Maybe have better solution?

this is my aspx clint code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="38px" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" Width="167px" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            The report is creating please wait...
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>
```

And next is my code behind

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            sendBackToUser();
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sendBackToUser();
        }

        private void sendBackToUser()
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\F\f.xlsx");
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + @"C:\F\f.xlsx");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you put a break point in your `Button1_Click` event, is the code reached or not ?

Comment: yes. this both go from start to end

Comment: Is it the 5 seconds waiting that makes it crash ? And what happens exactly for you to say it did not work ? (do you have an error message, exception, it just freezes ?)

Comment: On Button1_Click it just waits 5 seconds,
run all over the sendBackToUser();
get to } of Button1_Click,
finish and nothing happens 

But on Button2_Click
When its get to end its let me to download the Excel file

Comment: @AntoinePelletier having experienced the same problem before, I believe the issue is that the UpdatePanel is only doing a partial postback so what OP will see happening is, literally, nothing. It'll look like the button hasn't been clicked at all

Answer (score 0):

While the UpdatePanel is a perfectly suitable solution to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44946601/475766), you neglected to mention that you were trying to initiate a file download as well (you did say something about it in comments, but I didn't understand you clearly).

The problem with Button1 is because the UpdatePanel doesn't trigger a full PostBack of the page - it only posts back the content of the UpdatePanel.

As per [this answer regarding UpdatePanels and downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5461736/475766), you need to trigger a full PostBack:

Change your UpdatePanel like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    ...
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: UpdatePanel or asp:UpdatePanel?

Comment: Well spotted. Its always `<asp:UpdatePanel`

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your time

About what you said
At this case I can't see this  "The report is creating please wait..." message..

by the way, I saw somewhere that I have to add 
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(Button1);
I tried with this code and without.., 

And in both, I can't see this "The report is creating please wait..." message...

Comment: [Maybe have a look at this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1101546.aspx?Update+Progress+show+on+Ajax+Full+Postback+Trigger). You probably need an async postback to get all the functionality you want. Does your file download at least?

Comment: Yes, it is downloading

Comment: True, you need a full page reload to send a file to a client, i don't know how do you intend to show a progress bar during the time it's happening : when the file is being downloaded, there is a progress bar created by your browser if the file is big. Or do you want to show a progress bar during the time you are building the file in the code behind ?

Comment: without this OnClientClick, it's not shown to me the "The report is creating please wait...  "

And with OnClientClick this  "The report is creating please wait...  "  does not disappear.

In both cases the download work fine

Comment: Yes, I want to show this progress bar for this "Thread.Sleep(5000);"
action 

You can think about it as change text in the file and make it ready to send

Comment: @AntoinePelletier, Maybe Do you have another solution?

Comment: Well, i have a progress bar that works for every code behind in a project, answering with it now

Answer (score 0):

Here the waiting box in my project, wich is in a separate control :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WaitingBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="Web_GUI.Controls.WaitingBox" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="AlwaysVisibleControlExtender1" 
    runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel1" HorizontalSide="Center" 
    VerticalSide="Middle" HorizontalOffset="150">
</asp:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="waitingBox">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Please wait ...</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td id="cell_WaitingBox-Panel"><asp:Image ID="imgWaiting" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Themes/img/loading_animation.gif" /></td>
       </tr>    
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

And simply adding this to any other control that uses it :

```
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <MyControls:WaitingBox ID="wb2" runat="server" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Hope it inspire you... cause i don't exactly remember how it work.

But once it work, it can show a waiting box in all the control of your project.

I remember it shows a please wait message whenever the code behind is taking more than `DisplayAfter="100"` wich is 0.1 secondes maybe.

**EDIT Below code is in an other project, more simple**

js :

```
$.ajax({
url: "@Url.Action("create", "Post")",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify({ model: model})
}).done(function(result){
window.open('@Url.Action("Print", "controler", new { id = Model.id })', '_blank').focus();
});
```

code behind :

```
return Json( new { Whatever...});
```

But you rather try to call another javascript function so... forget you saw this

Comment: It may be a bit too complicated for your actual case... but it can serve you later.

Comment: my button is <MyControls:WaitingBox ID="wb2" runat="server" /> in your example?
or what?
I don't understand how do I convert your example to my...

by the way
What you think about something like 
l1 can be the label for this text  "The report is creating please wait... "
this will run in OnClientClick
<%
            l1.Visible = true;
    %>
  



and after the Thread.sleep do    l1.Visible = false;   in OnClick

Comment: Ho, if you take my example, you have to create a controller and paste my first block of code (without the headers) in it. Then register the controller in YOUR first block of code's header. Then, all you have to do is place my second block of code where a controller might cause a download, and the box will appear automatically without client side events. Yeah, that's pretty much what i remember, sorry if it doesn't help much.

Comment: document.getElementById('<% Response.Write(UpdateProgress1.ClientID); %>').style.display = "inline";

In this code

Can I change it back to style.display = none on the server side?

Comment: or can I run Javascript from serverside?

Comment: I know you can run Javascript from server side, i do it a lot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502897/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: But watch out for postbacks, sometime it's hard to combine both

Comment: What you mean? Why cant i change display to inline  when the function start.  And change to none when sleep end?

Comment: No, i want to hear what you think?  Its looks like you have deep knowlage

Comment: If i had to do any client side code, it would be javascript code that catches the button click event, show the image position fixed, and make an asynchronous call to the server (probably like you did for now) and then catch back with a JSON object...(see my edit).... Or yeah you could try, like you said, to trigger ANOTHER js function just before you send your download header

Comment: My example above does not fit (they are totally different projects) with the one below, just so you know

Comment: l1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
When I call it from code behind it does not work...
its keep the element inline

Comment: Because post backs ? Put a break point in your page load, to be sure.